# OTLv4 c++ how to get a response from request

Tags: c++, sql-server, database, odbc

I use `otlv4.h`, working with MS SQL and C++. The problem I have faced is I can't get the answer from a query that I sent for execution.

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was not difficult

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn0A1.png)